# Access time to WebElement.text increase

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I need to take data from a `JavaScript` site in real-time and I use:

```
while (True):
WebElement.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by 
import By options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--headless') 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) 
browser.get('s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/lmax-widget3/…) 
time.sleep(10) 
find_bid_price=browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[2]") 
while (True): 
    price=find_bid_price.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: Hi, please provide a more detailed description of what you are trying to achieve and provide show what code you already tried.

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

browser.get('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/lmax-widget3/website-widget-quote-vwap-flex.html')

time.sleep(10)

find_bid_price=browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[2]")

while (True):


    
    price=find_bid_price.get_attribute('innerHTML')

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the visibility of an element on the page and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/lmax-widget3/website-widget-quote-vwap-flex.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='lw_body']/div[@class='lw_book_title' and contains(., 'ORDER BOOK')]")))
  print(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  b'<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 ie6 ie">\n<![endif]--><!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie7 ie">\n<![endif]--><!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 ie8 ie"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 9]>         <html class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]--><!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="no-js lang-en" lang="en"><!--<![endif]--><head>\n    <title>LMAX quotes widget</title>\n\t<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1200" />\n\t<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />\n\t<style>\n\t\t#loader {\n\t\t    background: #FFFFFF;\n\t\t    display: block;\n\t\t\twidth: 290px;\n\t\t\theight: 225px;\n\t\t\tpadding: 2px 7px;\n\t\t    left: 0;\n\t\t    margin: 6px;\n\t\t    position: absolute;\n\t\t    top: 0;\n\t\t    z-index: 101;\n\t\t}\n\t</style>\n\t<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="media/widget/css/widget-flexible.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />\n    <!--[if lt IE 9]>\n      <script type="text/javascript" src="media/widget/js/html5.js"></script>\n    <![endif]-->\n    <!--[if lt IE 8]>\n\t \xc2\xa0<script type="text/javascript" src="media/widget/js/json2.min.js"></script>\n\t<![endif]-->\n\t<script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="media/widget/js/faye-client.js" style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85);"></script>\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="media/widget/js/lmax-widget-quotes-v2-extras.js"></script>\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="media/widget/js/lmax-widget-quotes-v2.min.js"></script>\n<script type="text/javascript" src="https://data-fix.smt-data.com/lmax?message=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmeta%2Fhandshake%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%2C%22supportedConnectionTypes%22%3A%5B%22websocket%22%2C%22eventsource%22%2C%22long-polling%22%2C%22cross-origin-long-polling%22%2C%22callback-polling%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D&amp;jsonp=__jsonp1__"></script></head>\n<body class="lw_hide_charts lw_show_vwap" style="line-height: 150px; font-size: 150px;">\n<div id="loader" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">\n\t<div></div>\n\t<img src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/logo.svg" alt="LMAX Professional" />\n\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/logo.swf" id="logo" name="logo">\n\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/logo.swf" />\n\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t</object>\n\t<![endif]-->\n</div>\n<div id="lw_alert" style="display: none;">\n\t<div class="lw_alert_error_title" id="lw_alert_error_title">LIVE PRICES</div>\n\t<div class="lw_alert_close_title" id="lw_alert_close_title">Markets closed</div>\n\t<div class="lw_alert_error_msg1" id="lw_alert_error_msg1">temporary connection error</div>\n\t<div class="lw_alert_error_msg2" id="lw_alert_error_msg2">reconnecting again automatically</div>\n\t<div class="lw_alert_close_msg1" id="lw_alert_close_msg1"><a href="http://www.lmax.com/average-spreads-fx" target="_top">view last week\xe2\x80\x99s spreads</a><br />\n\t\t<a href="http://www.lmax.com/execution-performance" target="_top">view recent latency figures</a><br />\n\t\t<a href="http://www.lmax.com/press-centre" target="_top">view latest news</a></div>\n\t<div class="lw_alert_error_icon">\t\n\t\t<img id="lw_alert_error_icon" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/error.svg" alt="" />\n\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/error.swf" id="error-swf" name="error-swf">\n\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/error.swf" />\n\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t</object>\n\t\t<![endif]-->\n\t</div>\n\t<div class="lw_alert_slogan">\n\t\t<img id="lw_alert_slogan" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/slogan.svg" alt="The Professional FX Exchange" />\n\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/.swf" id="slogan-swf" name="slogan-swf">\n\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/.swf" />\n\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t</object>\n\t\t<![endif]-->\n\t</div>\n\t<div class="lw_alert_bg">\n\t\t<img id="lw_alert_bg" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/alert.svg" alt="" />\n\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/alert.swf" id="alert-swf" name="alert-swf">\n\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/alert.swf" />\n\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t</object>\n\t\t<![endif]-->\n\t</div>\n</div>\n<div class="lw_main">\n\t<div id="dummy"></div>\n    <div class="lw_inner_container">\n        <div class="lw_header">\n\t\t\t<div id="lw_brand"><img id="lw_brand_bg" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/lmax-digital.svg" alt="" /></div>\n\t\t\t<div class="lw_book_title" id="lw_topbook_title">TOP OF BOOK</div>\n        \t<div class="lw_tl_ribbon" id="lw_tlBanner" style="display: none;"></div>\n\t\t\t<div class="lw_instru_logo">\n\t\t\t\t<img id="lw_instru_logo" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/topleft-logo.svg" alt="" />\n\t\t\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/topleft-logo.swf" id="topleft-logo" name="topleft-logo">\n\t\t\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/topleft-logo.swf" />\n\t\t\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t\t\t</object>\n\t\t\t\t<![endif]-->\n\t\t\t</div>\n            <div class="lw_instru_name">EUR/USD</div>\n            <div class="lw_instru_symbol" style="display: none;">EURUSD</div>\n            <div class="lw_instru_spread_value spread_price gradient">0.00</div>\n            <div class="lw_instru_arrow">\n                <img id="lw_instru_arrow" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/arrow_right.svg" alt="&gt;" />\n\t\t\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/arrow_right.swf" id="arrow_right" name="arrow_right">\n\t\t\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/arrow_right.swf" />\n\t\t\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t\t\t</object>\n\t\t\t\t<![endif]-->\n            </div>\n            <div class="lw_instru">\n                <div class="lw_hide_chart_label">\n\t\t\t\t\t<img id="lw_hide_chart_label" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/close.svg" alt="X" />\n\t\t\t\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t\t\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/close.swf" id="close" name="close">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/close.swf" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t\t\t\t</object>\n\t\t\t\t\t<![endif]-->\n                </div>\n                <div class="lw_instru_dropdown_label">CHOOSE INSTRUMENT</div>\n                <div class="lw_instru_list_overlay mCustomScrollbar _mCS_1 mCS_no_scrollbar" style="top: 149px;"><div id="mCSB_1" class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light mCSB_vertical mCSB_inside" tabindex="0" style="max-height: 771px;"><div id="mCSB_1_container" class="mCSB_container mCS_no_scrollbar_y" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;" dir="ltr">\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class="lw_instru_list"></ul>\t\n                </div><div id="mCSB_1_scrollbar_vertical" class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_1_scrollbar mCS-light mCSB_scrollTools_vertical"><div class="mCSB_draggerContainer"><div id="mCSB_1_dragger_vertical" class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; min-height: 23.26px; display: none; top: 0px;" oncontextmenu="return false;"><div class="mCSB_dragger_bar"></div></div><div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div></div></div></div></div>\n            </div>\n        </div>\n\t\t<div class="lw_vwap block">\t\t\t\n\t\t\t<div class="lw_vwap_top" id="lw_vwap_main_title">VWAP</div>\n\t\t\t<div class="lw_vwap_left">\n\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_vwap_name">\n\t\t\t\t\t<label class="lw_vwap_label" id="lw_vwap_amount_label" for="lw_vwap_amount">AMOUNT</label>\n\t\t\t\t\t<input class="lw_vwap_value" type="text" value="1M" id="lw_vwap_amount" />\n\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_vwap_name">\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_vwap_label" id="lw_vwap_bid_label">BID</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_vwap_value" id="lw_vwap_bid">0.00000</div>\n\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t<div class="lw_vwap_right">\n\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_vwap_name">\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_vwap_label" id="lw_vwap_ask_label">ASK</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_vwap_value" id="lw_vwap_ask">0.00000</div>\n\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_vwap_name">\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_vwap_label" id="lw_vwap_spread_label">SPREAD</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_vwap_value" id="lw_vwap_spread">0.00000</div>\n\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t</div>\n        <div class="lw_body">\n\t\t\t<div class="lw_book_title" id="lw_orderbook_title">ORDER BOOK</div>\n            <div class="lw_body_column lw_column_left">\n                <div class="lw_body_top">\n                    <div class="lw_bid_arrow lw_ask_arrow_up">\n                    \t<img id="lw_ask_arrow_up" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/up.svg" alt="\xe2\x86\x91" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/up.swf" id="askup" name="askup">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/up.swf" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</object>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<![endif]-->\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n                    <div class="lw_bid_arrow lw_ask_arrow_down">\n                    \t<img id="lw_ask_arrow_down" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/down.svg" alt="\xe2\x86\x91" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/down.swf" id="askdown" name="askdown">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/down.swf" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</object>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<![endif]-->\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_bid_arrow lw_ask_arrow_right">\n                    \t<img id="lw_ask_arrow_right" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/right.svg" alt="\xe2\x86\x92" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/right.swf" id="askright" name="askright">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/right.swf" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</object>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<![endif]-->\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n                    <div class="lw_bid_label" id="lw_bid_label">BID</div>\n                    <div class="clear"></div>\n                    <div class="lw_row">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_0">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_0">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                        <input class="old_price" type="hidden" value="0" />\n                    </div>\n                    <hr />\n                </div>\n                <div class="lw_body_list" id="lw_body_list_bid">\n                    <div class="lw_row">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_1">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_1">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_2">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_2">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_3">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_3">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_4">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_4">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_5">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_5">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row  extra even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_6">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_6">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_7">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_7">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row extra even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_8">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_8">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_9">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_9">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row extra even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_10">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_10">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_11">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_11">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row  extra even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_12">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_12">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_13">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_13">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row extra even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_14">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_14">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_15">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_15">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row extra even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_16">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_16">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_17">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_17">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row extra even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_18">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_18">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_bid_amount bid_amount_19">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price bid_price_19">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                </div>\n            </div>\n            <div class="lw_body_column lw_column_right">\n                <div class="lw_body_top">\n                    <div class="lw_bid_arrow lw_bid_arrow_up">\n                    \t<img id="lw_bid_arrow_up" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/up.svg" alt="\xe2\x86\x91" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/up.swf" id="bidup" name="bidup">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/up.swf" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</object>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<![endif]-->\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n                    <div class="lw_bid_arrow lw_bid_arrow_down">\n                    \t<img id="lw_bid_arrow_down" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/down.svg" alt="\xe2\x86\x93" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/down.swf" id="biddown" name="biddown">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/down.swf" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</object>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<![endif]-->\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_bid_arrow lw_bid_arrow_left">\n                    \t<img id="lw_bid_arrow_left" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/left.svg" alt="\xe2\x86\x90" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/left.swf" id="askleft" name="askleft">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/left.swf" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</object>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<![endif]-->\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n                    <div class="lw_ask_label" id="lw_ask_label">ASK</div>\n                    <div class="clear"></div>\n                    <div class="lw_row">\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_0">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_0">0</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                        <input class="old_price" type="hidden" value="0" />\n                    </div>\n                    <hr />\n                </div>\n                <div class="lw_body_list" id="lw_body_list_ask">\n                    <div class="lw_row">\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_1">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_1">0</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row even">\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_2">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_2">0</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row">\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_3">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_3">0</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row even">\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_4">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_4">0</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_5">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_5">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row  extra even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_6">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_6">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_7">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_7">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row extra even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_8">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_8">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_9">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_9">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row extra even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_10">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_10">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_11">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_11">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row  extra even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_12">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_12">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_13">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_13">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row extra even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_14">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_14">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="lw_row extra">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_15">0</div>\n                        <div class="lw_price ask_price_15">0.00000</div>\n                        <div class="clear"></div>\n                    </div>\n                    <div class="lw_row extra even">\n                        <div class="lw_amount lw_ask_amount ask_amount_16">0</div>\n                        <div id="lw_footer_main" class="lw_footer">\n            <span class="lw_footer_main">1 FX contract = 10,000 notional - for CFD contracts click <a target="_blank" href="http://www.lmax.com/instruments/cfd-trading">here</a></span><br />\n\t\t\t<span class="lw_footer_info">(LMAX Professional open Order Book - first 5 levels only displayed)</span>\n        </div>\n    </div>\n</div>\n<div class="lw_range lw_range_alt">\n\t<div class="lw_range_icon">\n\t\t<img id="lw_range_icon_alt" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/spreads.svg" alt="SPREADS" />\n\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/spreads.swf" id="spreads" name="spreads">\n\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/spreads.swf" />\n\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t</object>\n\t\t<![endif]-->\n\t</div>\n\t<div class="lw_range_arrow">\n\t\t<img id="lw_range_arrow_alt" src="media/widget/images_multi/prof/arrow_right.svg" alt="&gt;" />\n\t\t<!--[if IE]>\n\t\t<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/widget/images_multi/prof/arrow_right.swf" id="arrow_right2" name="arrow_right2">\n\t\t\t<param name="movie" value="media/widget/images_multi/prof/arrow_right.swf" />\n\t\t\t<param name="quality" value="high" />\n\t\t\t<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />\n\t\t\t<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />\n\t\t\t<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />\n\t\t</object>\n\t\t<![endif]-->\n\t</div>\n\t<div class="lw_range_name today_symbol" id="lw_chart_today_alt">Today</div>\n\t<div class="lw_range_name week_symbol" id="lw_chart_week_alt">Week</div>\n\t<div class="lw_range_name month_symbol" id="lw_chart_month_alt">Month</div>\n</div>\n<div id="lw_footer_alt" class="lw_footer lw_footer_alt">\n\t<span class="lw_footer_main" id="lw_vwap_footer_main">1 FX contract = <span id="lw_footer_lotsize">10000</span> notional - for CFD contracts click <a target="_blank" href="http://www.lmax.com/instruments/cfd-trading">here</a></span><br />\n\t<span class="lw_footer_info"></span>\n</div>\n\n</body></html>'
  ```